# What is known about the number of elements needed to generate a given ideal in $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

In *Algebraic Geometry* by J.S. Milne, after he proves Hilbert's Basis Theorem, he makes the following aside:

> One may ask how many elements are needed to generate a given a given ideal $\mathfrak a$ in $k[X_1,\dots,x_n]$, or, what is not quite the same thing, how many equations are needed to define a given algebraic set $V$. [...] Determining exactly how many is an area of active research.

He gives some references to the question about algebraic sets. However, as far as I can tell, he does not provide any references to the question about ideals. Presumably, it is not possible to give a satisfying general answer to how many elements are needed to generate a given ideal in $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, but are there any partial results in this direction?

Comment: What data is put in? With no conditions, there are ideals ( say powers of a maximal ideal) or even prime ideals which require arbitrarily large number of generators. If the variety is smooth, there are much better estimates. There are also theorems like Forster's theorem, Eisenbud-Evans theorem which give estimates knowing local number of generators.

Comment: @Mohan: Thank you for responding. My intention for this question was for it to be quite broad (perhaps it is too broad), and so I think all of the results you mention are relevant. I just wanted to see an overview of what is known – I didn't have anything particular in mind.

Comment: Many results are covered in Kunz's Commutative Algebra and Ischebeck- Rao's Ideals and Reality.

Comment: @Mohan: do you mean "Introduction to Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry" and "Ideals and Reality: Projective Modules and Number of Generators of Ideals" ?

Comment: @M.G. Yes, that is what I meant

Comment: @Mohan: Thank you, I browsed through both of those references and they seem to be very helpful. You can turn your comment into an answer, if you wish.